# VHDL Code explanation needed (std_logic_vector)

Tags: vhdl, fpga

1) `std_logic_vector(data_width - 1 downto 0)`

In this code, I am not understanding (-1 downto 0). I know this is telling us that it is 8 bit. But Not understanding how? For example, (7 donwto 0) is self-explanatory eg. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

2) `A_reg(data_width - 1 downto 1) <= A_reg(data_width - 2 downto 0);`

I know we are left shifting. But can anyone explain how? I wanted to know how the bit position is changing or shifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read very carefully. It does *not* say (**-1** downto 0). it says (**data_width - 1** downto 0).

Thus if data_width is 8 you get (8-1 downto 0) which is your (7 downto 0)

---

Now the next one: `A_reg(data_width - 1 downto 1) <= A_reg(data_width - 2 downto 0);`

Again using a data_width of 8 we get : `A_reg(7 downto 1) <= A_reg(6 downto 0);`

Thus the bits 6,5,4,...0 are transferred to resp bits 7,6,5,..1. Each bit is moved one position to the left, but bit 0 stays the same:

```
 A[7][6][5][4][3][2][1][0]
     /  /  /  /  /  /  /|
    /  /  /  /  /  /  / | 
   v  v  v  v  v  v  v  v
 A[7][6][5][4][3][2][1][0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation is so nice and clear.